# Mousewheel on vertical Swiper carousel doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying to add mousewheel control to my SwiperJS carousel, but it doesnt seem to work. Looks like that just by adding `mousewheel: true` should do a trick, but it doesnt.  I cannot find and support in offical documentation. Am I missing something ?

Here is example: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-forked-d5oic?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the their [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mousewheel-control-example-evnhy) on the [github](https://github.com/kidjp85/react-id-swiper/blob/dc9eed56aad055a50cdd5415e8e899184f2c6665/docs/live-examples.md) it would seem they developed this feature prior to `Swiper` `6.x.x`

If you use `5.4.5` like they did in their example, the mousewheel functions should work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-forked-155qs